# Getting the sum of entries that match the conditions from 2 columns

Tags: excel

I have this setup in my worksheet

[image]

where column A contains the conditions I need to look out for,

column B contains the total number of records that fit the conditions,

and columns D and E contain the records I need to count

---

what I want to happen is to create a formula for column B where it can count the total records that fit 2 conditions I need

for example in the case of B3, there are 2 instances of Dog Red in column E where column D contains the word small, and for B3 there is only 1 instance of Dog Red where column D contains the word large

the same conditions apply for the rest of column B

---

is there a way to compute for the total records that fit the 2 conditions in a single cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula below will work for B3:B4. For B6:B7 the reference to `A$2` would have to be changed manually.

```
=COUNTIFS($E$3:$E$9,A$2,$D$3:$D$9,"*"&A3&"*")
```

It should be possible to extend the formula to be able to find the right color dog in column A so that you can copy the formula down all the way without change. I haven't done this here because I feel your example isn't representative of your final worksheet. For the moment, please just take note that your arrangement of count criteria makes referencing them difficult. Perhaps a better way of displaying them can be found.

Comment: I guess you could add a standard formula for finding the last non-blank text in column A if you wanted to make it less manual https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell =LOOKUP(2,1/(A$2:A2<>""),A$2:A2)